# DirectAdmin hosting - default page redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, host, directadmin

I host my website on DirectAdmin, the domain is redirected to `example.com/wp`, I have deleted all the `wp` files and redirect the domain to `example.com/index.html`, but nothings has been changed.
I also update the `.htaccess` file too

```
Directory Index index.html
Redirect 301 / http:example.com/index.html
```

but it still open the `example.com/wp` as the default page.

how I can force it to open the `index.html` page in `public_html` folder through the default domain?

Comment: What is the host domain in your Settings->General Settings ? Make sure this is set properly.

Comment: I check it, it set properly as example .com

Comment: I think you might want to set your 'Document Root' for your domain in the DirectAdmin interface as opposed to doing a redirect.

Comment: That's work. Thank you :)